Example of new Firebase HTTP v1 iOS JSON Payload notification syntax
I've looked at a bunch of posts, including the related questions to this one, but there are no examples of the real syntax. Here is an example of my legacy silent Apple notification:
{
  "to": "%MobileUser.DeviceId%",
  "content_available": true,
  "apns-push-type": "background",
  "data": {
    "notificationId": "%Some.Id%",
    "KeyOne": "%Val.One%",
    "KeyTwo": "%Val.One%",
  }
}

So I've tried prepending:
  "message": {
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
          "aps": { 
              "token": "blah"
              "notification": {
                "title": "whatever",
                "body": ""
              },
              "content_available": true,
              "apns-push-type": "background",
              "data": {  etc etc

but I always get bad requests.  Is there any place where I can get exact syntax?  I got the Android side working, but not the Apple side.  I know you can combine them now, but I don't need to do that.  I just have to get good syntax for these messages, both silent and normal.   Thanks

Well -- I think I have the iOS syntax down -- just add an apns section after data:
"apns": {
"headers": {
"apns-push-type" : "background"
},
"payload": {
"aps":  {
"content-avalable": "1"
},
"fcm_options": {}
}
},
